# Android ResourceNotFound exception

Tags: android

I have two values directories - one for English and one default.
if the resource are located in any of those folders, i can use it.
But if there is no resource in default values directory and locale is other than English, it causes `ResourceNotFoundException`.
I understand why this happens and why Android was built this way (to prevent ambiguous resource usage in case there are more than one non-default resource files with this resource).
But is there any way to force `Android` use, for example, English resource bundle if resource couldn't be found?

Comment: cant you just copy the english into default?

Comment: well the resources are generated and I don't always know if they exist in both resources or not. I am talking about String resources, to be more specific.

Comment: what you mean by *generated* ?

Comment: @RooMan what Blackbelt mean is you need to copy all english string constants (resources) in your default `Values -> strings.xml` file.

Comment: I mean, resources I should use throughout my applications are created on serverside and strings.xml is in my maven dependency. I just copy them in corresponding folder.

Comment: no! I am creating app for Norway. That is why Norwegian is default and English is just extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option you have is to make sure the `/res/values/strings.xml` file contains every string in English but you must also have `/res/values-no/strings.xml` which has the Norwegian strings.

If `/res/values-no/strings.xml` doesn't have the resource it will drop back to `/res/values/strings.xml`. It's the only way to do it.

Comment: Okay, I will just blame server guys if thay fail to generate String resources correctly. I have to use /res/values/strings.xml and /res/values-en/strings.xml